# 「ios apple 公式ドキュメントのサンプルコードについて」の質問はオフトピック?

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲

- [ios apple 公式ドキュメントのサンプルコードについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/43579/754)

上記質問は、現在オフトピックとしてクローズされています。これは、果たしてオフトピックでしょうか? この質問は、「公式 Document を見てみたが、サンプルコードが見なれない。ドキュメントを読むにあたって objective-C の理解は必要か」という内容です。

個人的には、「質問がはっきりしない」ないし「主観的な答えしか集まらない」、「質問範囲が広すぎる」はありえても、オフトピックではないのではないか、と思います。というのも、今回の質問者の状況は、おそらく次の通りではないかと推測ができるからです。

1. swift を用いて開発を行っている
2. 何か個別のフレームワークオブジェクトなどを取り扱う必要がでてきたので、公式ドキュメントを参照した
3. そこで出てくるソースコードが objective-C のものしかなかった。
4. なので、さてどうしたものか、と思っている。

この状況に遭遇した開発者が、次に取るべきアクションを尋ねる旨の質問は、個人的にはこれはスタックオーバーフローが取り扱う質問の範疇の中にあると思います。具体的には、次の項目に当てはまるのではないかと思います。

> - プログラミング上の具体的な問題

また、仮に、これが何らかの理由でスタックオーバーフローの取り扱う質問の範疇に入っていなかったとしても、それに対するレスポンスが、「ヘルプセンターの定義から外れている」だけでは、上記の理由で、質問者にとっては何が原因で改善待ち・クローズされているのか、明確ではないと思います。

Comment: この質問に回答した者ですが、回答してはいけなかったでしょうか

Comment: @Чайка いいえ。Чайкаさんの回答には何ひとつ問題はなく、むしろ優れた投稿であると思っています。今現在、この質問は、[クローズ済み](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)という状態になっています。これは何かというと、このコミュニティとしては、当該の質問に対する回答をこれ以上は受け付けません、という意思表示です。これは、[クローズ投票](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)によってなされます。個人的に、このクローズ投票の際に用いられた理由が、適切ではないのではないかと思ったので、このメタ投稿をしている次第です。回答者は、回答できるならば、基本的にガンガン回答投稿してくれた方がよい、と個人的には思っています。

Comment: ♦ 了解です。ありがとうございます。僕も（クローズ前の質問が）放置されていては、「質問しても誰も答えてくれない役に立たないサイト」と見做されてしまうのは惜しいと思うので、可能な際はこれからも回答していきたいと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

オフトピックか？という疑問に対してはそうではないと思います。
ただし、質問文中での`あのサンプルコード`が何を指すのか不明であり、
何処で疑問を持ったのか分からないため、アドバイスしづらいかとは思います。
(議題で仰っているように、「主観的な答えしか集まらない」「質問範囲が広すぎる」ですかね)

Comment: マイナス票を入れた方、マイナス点について説明を頂きたいです。何が問題なのかコメントもしくは回答をお願いします。